# LUKS-Encrypted Root Partition in Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption

I have a LUKS-encrypted root partition that I have installed Ubuntu 9.04 to.  I have of course placed /boot on a separate ext2 partition, and my boot loader loads and functions correctly.

However, I can't seem to get my initrd to load the LUKS-encrypted root using the appropriate /dev/mapper/ address.  What hooks and scripts do I need to add to get this to function correctly, and what is the correct way to regenerate my initrd?

I can CHROOT into this install, and everything works fine - but I just can't seem to get it to actually boot. Help!

Comment: Could you show your `/etc/crypttab` and `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for additional steps:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1138774

Hope this helps!
-pbr